# Can I use a 'LIKE' statement in a SSIS job to check if filename exists?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I have an SSIS job to load flat files into a database. I load the file name into a column in the SQL database. In the first step I check to see if the file name already exists. If it does the file gets deleted. If not it gets processed and loaded. The original file is a .dat. The problem is that because of another process the file gets loaded is renamed with a "_flat.txt" appended to the end of the name and does not match the original.

> "YC_HSO_PA_0_Test_1.dat"

"YC_HSO_PA_0_Test_1_flat.txt"

The variable that stores the original name of the file is 'User::FileNameCheck'. The table I check against is TOC.PA_STAGE. The expression I use to do the check is:

```
"DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR (100)
SET @FileName =  '"+ @[User::FileNameCheck]  +"'

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM [TOC].[PA_STAGE]
            WHERE FileName = @FileName)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS LoadStatusFlag
    END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 1 AS LoadStatusFlag
END"
```

I tried this:

```
"DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR (100)
SET @FileName =  REPLACE(REPLACE(@[User::FileNameCheck],'.txt',''),'.dat','')  +'_flat.txt' 

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM [TOC].[PA_STAGE]
            WHERE FileName = @FileName)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS LoadStatusFlag
    END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 1 AS LoadStatusFlag
END"
```

but get an error: SET @FileName =  R..." failed with the following error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@".".

Can I use a 'LIKE' statement to find file names to match. Or somehow append the _flat.txt to the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is not expanding the value of @[User::FileNameCheck]. Try:

```
"DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR (100)
SET @FileName =  REPLACE(REPLACE('" + @[User::FileNameCheck] + "','.txt',''),'.dat','')  +'_flat.txt' 

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM [TOC].[PA_STAGE]
            WHERE FileName = @FileName)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS LoadStatusFlag
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 1 AS LoadStatusFlag
END"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you Magnus.